# How to create a table (in excel file) with elements that represent fixed size intervals

Tags: excel-formula, ms-office

I want help to create same kind of file with a table whose elements are intervals with a fixed size of 10. The intervals should start at 15001 and end with 20000. I have attached a sample image of the excel sheet below. Please help me and tell me a method of creating such file which involves minimum typing.
Please help me.

[I have also attached a image table for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmdHa.jpg)

Comment: I have improved the title so it is more generic. I have also clarified the question.

Comment: **thanks for your help**

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  The simplest is to enter your starting number in cell A1.  Then in Cell A2 enter

```
=($A$1+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*10+(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$2))*650)&" to "&($A$1+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*10+(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$2))*650)+9
```

Copy that down till is has the number you want shown, and then copy all the formulas from the A column to the right.

Size and format your cells to suit your needs.

IF you do not want to put 1501 in cell $A$1 then in the formula replace $A$1 with 1501.

$A$2 will need to be adjusted to the cell you are using for your top left corner.

### Explination

```
=($A$1+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*10+(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$2))*650)
```

This part of the formula determines the first number.  you will notice you see it repeated exactly twice.  At the end of the second repetition +9 was added to it to get the second number.

```
($A$1+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*10+(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$2))*650)+9
```

Once you have the two numbers figured out we glue them together so to speak by place a little concatenation sequence in between:

```
&" to "&
```

The important part here was to leave a space on either side of the word "to" so that when the numbers were place on either side there would be a space as well.

So how did that ugly formula work out to be a number?  Well first we needed a starting point which was the Value in $A$1.  In this case also 1501.  Then we look at the pattern for the first number going down.  Every row it increases by 10.  So that means 1501+(each row)*10.  So we need a way to count each row.  I chose to do this with:

```
row()-row($A$2)
```

Row() without an address in it tell you the number of the row you are currently in.  $A$2 is the address of the top left corner of the table.  So if that formula were in the top left corner it would return a value of 2-2 = 0, and for the next row down it would be 3-2 = 1.  So now we have a nice little counter going down and that is how we wound up with:

```
=$A$1+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*10
```

Now we need to take care of the portion of how to increase the first number as we go across the columns.  Looking at the pattern it increase 650 for each column.  So similar to are ROW() function there is a COLUMN() function.  We apply the same concepts that we did for the row calculation and add it to the formula we already have:

```
=$A$1+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*10+(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$2)*650
```

now technically speaking if you are doing this with A1 being your top left corner you can simplify the equation, and hardcode in the initial number and calculate your starting numbers with:

```
=1501+(ROW()-1)*10+(COLUMN()-1)*650
```

Comment: thank you @Forward Ed for all the help

Comment: thank you @Forward Ed for all the help

but instead of 15001 to 15010 as result I'm getting 15001 to 15011 in A1 and 15011 to 15021 in A2 and so on hence 15011 get repeated in the next row. (a1 and a2) 

If you can provide any solution for that then it would be really helpful for my project.

Comment: my mistake I will make a quick tweak to that formula.  Instead of adding 10 at the very end we add 9

Comment: @ankitrathore yes, just highlight all the cells in column A that you wasn to copy, and then highlight all the column B, C, D, E,....etc for an equal multiple of rows and paste.  OR select all the cells in column A then click and drag the outline of the selection to the right for the desired number of columns